# Clicking noise when stopping and accelerating. AC issue?

Tags: ac, noise, acceleration, braking, dashboard

I drive a 2014 Corolla LE. Whenever I accelerate or brake, I get a tap or a click from within the dashboard near the center vent area.

#### It happens when...

- I accelerate from a stop.
- I just tap the accelerator while rolling.
- Right before coming to a complete stop.
- I change the CVT gear from Drive to Reverse and Reverse to Drive.

#### Observations:

- The noise is greatly reduced on cold days.
- Oddly, the sound goes away when the AC is on.
- As soon as I press the AC button from off to on, the noise disappears.
- Sometimes the noise occurs when I press the AC button from off to on.

I believe it has to do with some electrical AC component, like a relay or actuator.

[Video of clicking noise. Increase volume to hear the noise.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mc8sw4g_mY)

#### Questions:

1. What could be causing this noise?
2. How do I diagnose this?